# Sql function in magento

Tags: query

Can we use sql functions like MAX() MIN() for magento collection rather than the query mentioned in this post ?

[How To Get Min & Max Attribute Values From Database to Link to Price Slider](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5710/how-to-get-min-max-attribute-values-from-database-to-link-to-price-slider)

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like below.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('modulename/modulename')->getCollection(); 

$collection->getSelect()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns('MAX(your_index) as max_aliases');
```